# How do you call a function in another function using the right parameters in visual basics

Tags: vba, function, parameters

I keep getting errors and it won't let me use my `isworthy` function inside the other functions:

```
Private Function isworthy(ByVal home As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim score As Double
    Dim income As Double
    If home = True Then
        Return "True"
    ElseIf score < 500 Then
        Return "False"
    ElseIf income >= 12000 Then
        Return "True"
    Else
        Return "False"
    End If
End Function

Private Function cardtype(ByVal score As Double, ByVal income As Double) As Double
    If isworthy() = False Then
        Return "N/A"
    ElseIf score >= 750 And income >= 20000 Then
        Return "Gold"
    ElseIf score >= 650 And income >= 15000 Then
        Return "Silver"
    Else
        Return "Basic"
    End If
End Function

Private Function interestrate(ByVal cardtype() As Double) As String
    If isworthy() = False Then
        Return "N/A"
    ElseIf cardtype() = "Gold" Then
        Return "2%"
    ElseIf cardtype() = "Silver" Then
        Return "8%"
    ElseIf cardtype() = "Basic" Then
        Return "22%"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear until you can at least figure out what language you're using. Your title says *Visual Basics*, but you tagged it *vba* and *Visual C++* (which it clearly isn't). If you don't know what language you're using, you clearly can't write code in it. (You should also learn to read and understand your own code (or the code you're copy/pasting); if you did, you'd see that your declaration of `isworthy` requires a parameter, which your code that tries to call it does not pass.)

Answer (score 0):

1) Isworthy is private
2) isworthy doesnt contain a boolean valuable anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues:

```
Private Function isworthy(ByVal home As Boolean) As Boolean
    Dim score As Double
    Dim income As Double
    If home = True Then
        Return "True"
    ElseIf score < 500 Then
        Return "False"
    ElseIf income >= 12000 Then
        Return "True"
    Else
        Return "False"
    End If
End Function
```

Given it's possible to 'overload' functions in VBA (have multiple functions with same name, but requiring different types or amounts of arguments), you need to be precise in how you call it. Your function definition says it takes a boolean as parameter, but you call it without feeding it a parameter. Correct call would be 'isworthy(true)', but 'isworthy()' will not work.

Also, if you'd call it correctly, it'd still be of little use:
You dim score and income as double, but they are not assigned any values.
Therefore, if the function gets called at all, it'll assume '0' for both, and always return false.

Based on that, I'd say you need something more like this:

```
Private Function isworthy(ByVal home As Boolean, ByVal score As Double, ByVal income As Double) As Boolean
    If home = True Then
            Return "True"
        ElseIf score < 500 Then
            Return "False"
        ElseIf income >= 12000 Then
            Return "True"
        Else
            Return "False"
        End If
    End Function
```

And call it like:

> isworthy(home,score,income)